# filter out tokens that occur exactly once in a gensim dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, gensim

The gensim dictionary object has a very nice filtering function to remove tokens that appear in fewer than a set amount of documents. However, I am looking to remove tokens that occur exactly once in the *corpus*. Does anyone know of a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably include some reproducible code in your question; however, I'll use the documents from the previous post. We can accomplish your goal without using gensim.

```
from collections import defaultdict
documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
              "The EPS user interface management system",
              "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
              "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
              "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
              "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
              "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
              "Graph minors A survey"]

# remove common words and tokenize
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in documents]

# word frequency
d=defaultdict(int)
for lister in texts:
    for item in lister:
        d[item]+=1

# remove words that appear only once
tokens=[key for key,value in d.items() if value>1]
texts = [[word for word in document if word in tokens] for document in texts]
```

---

---

To add some info though, you might consider that the gensim tutorial also has a more memory efficient technique in addition to the previously mentioned method. I added some print statements so you can see what's happening at each step. Your specific question is answered in the DICTERATOR step; I realize the following answer may be overkill for your question, but if you need to do any sort of topic modeling then this info will be a step in the right direction.

```
$cat mycorpus.txt

Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications
A survey of user opinion of computer system response time
The EPS user interface management system
System and human system engineering testing of EPS
Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement
The generation of random binary unordered trees
The intersection graph of paths in trees
Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering
Graph minors A survey
```

Run the following create_corpus.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())

class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open('mycorpus.txt'):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split()) 

# TOKENIZERATOR: collect statistics about all tokens
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open('mycorpus.txt'))
print (dictionary)
print (dictionary.token2id)

# DICTERATOR: remove stop words and words that appear only once 
stop_ids = [dictionary.token2id[stopword] for stopword in stoplist if stopword in dictionary.token2id]
once_ids = [tokenid for tokenid, docfreq in dictionary.dfs.iteritems() if docfreq == 1]
dictionary.filter_tokens(stop_ids + once_ids)
print (dictionary)
print (dictionary.token2id)

dictionary.compactify() # remove gaps in id sequence after words that were removed
print (dictionary)
print (dictionary.token2id)

# VECTORERATOR: map tokens frequency per doc to vectors
corpus_memory_friendly = MyCorpus() # doesn't load the corpus into memory!
for item in corpus_memory_friendly:
    print item
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to lookup the gensim dictionary [filter_extremes](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.filter_extremes) method:

filter_extremes(no_below=5, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the Gensim [tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html):

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities

documents = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
             "The EPS user interface management system",
             "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
             "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
             "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
             "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
             "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
             "Graph minors A survey"]
# remove common words and tokenize
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
         for document in documents]

# remove words that appear only once
all_tokens = sum(texts, [])
tokens_once = set(word for word in set(all_tokens) if all_tokens.count(word) == 1)
texts = [[word for word in text if word not in tokens_once]
        for text in texts]
print texts

[['human', 'interface', 'computer'],
 ['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time'],
 ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system'],
 ['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps'],
 ['user', 'response', 'time'],
 ['trees'],
 ['graph', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'survey']]
```

Basically, iterate through a list containing the entire corpus, and if each word only occurs once, add it to a list of tokens. Then iterate through each word in each document and remove the word if it was in the list of tokens that appear once in the corpus.

I'm assuming this is the best way to do it, otherwise the tutorial would have mentioned something else. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_term_frequency(dictionary,cutoff_freq):
    """This returns a list of tuples (term,frequency) after removing all tuples with frequency smaller than cutoff_freq
       dictionary (gensim.corpora.Dictionary): corpus dictionary
       cutoff_freq (int): terms with whose frequency smaller than this will be dropped
    """
    tf = []
    for k,v in dictionary.dfs.iteritems():
        tf.append((str(dictionary.get(k)),v))
    return reduce(lambda t:t[1]>cutoff_freq)
```